# Down to just one "needs work" category on Area51

Tags: discussion

Great news: our "visits/day" rating has just gone from "needs work" to "ok". That's a big step.

We've only got one category that needs work now: questions per day.

So, we need more questions, and more corresponding answers.

So, if you see questions elsewhere on the web that would be a good fit here, and that you understand and could provide clarification on what's being asked, here's an idea:

Copy and paste the question to the main site, if the source licensing permits it. Otherwise, paraphrase the question. Add a link back to where the question came from (i.e. cite your sources). And add a link at the original question, point to the question here, insofar as the rules and guidelines on that site allow it (please don't spam on our behalf)

Do you have any other ways to increase the rate of quality content generation here on sustainability.SE?

Comment: Please be careful doing this. Consider carefully the unintended consequences of "seeding" a site like this simply to pump up your numbers — http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/ If there's a sense that the users asking these questions don't really care about the answers (i.e. these aren't problems the author is actually having), the folks who put their real time into *answering* these questions might perceive this exercise as a big waste of time. And remember that **not all Internet content is licensed for copying.**